# Why was there a robot in Rocky IV?

Tags: plot-explanation, production, rocky-iv

In Rocky IV (1985), Balboa gifts Paulie a talking and moving robot which could do following things:

- Talk and act like humans.
- Patch up to phone lines in house.
- Voice modulation according to needs. Paulie teaches it to talk in girl's voice.
- Provide household service.

[image]

It's almost like an combination of Artificial Intelligence and Internet of Things in today's time.

But it did not have any significance to the plot. Why was it included ?

Comment: I think the presence of the robot in the film is an additional indicator that Rocky's fortune is being systematically squandered.

Comment: @PCARR: If you are referring to his loss of fortune then that's story of 5th part. Also the reasons are different.

Comment: Doesn't it just represent how people spend on extravagant things when they think they have money just burning a hole in their pocket?

Comment: @PCARR Any reservations to fleshing that out into a proper answer?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths Any reservations to fleshing that out into a proper answer?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I really don't have anything to back it up as an answer in this particular situation.  I liken it to a rookie NFL player buying Ferraris and mansions when they should be investing and securing their future when they inevitably get hurt or retire.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths You seem to have a *reasonable explanation* to back it up. Backing things up isn't just about Wikipedia quotes.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Some interesting info can be found [here](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/film/creed/rocky-iv-robot-butler-stallone/).

Basically, to summarize the article, Stallone discovered the company that produced the robot was using it as a tool to help autistic children.  One of Stallone's children is autistic, so he became enamored with the robot and offered to write a part for it in the next Rocky movie.  Apparently there was more scripted around building the relationship between Paulie and the robot, but it was scrapped.

Comment: This is an incredibly wholesome answer, especially when contrasted against the comments on the question.

Comment: Does that mean within the film they are comparing Paulie to an autistic child?

Comment: No, because the autism angle isn't known within the Rockyverse.  It's just a companion.  Think of it as free ad placements.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Sounds like a pretty, shiny example of product placement. Interesting, whether company has actually paid for this ad or whether it was Stallone's decision: "Either this robot or I'm not playing in this damn movie!"?

Comment: @trejder - You can do that when a) you're the main actor, and b) you write the script.  ;o)

Comment: @JohnnyBones: Well... you can always drop playing in the movie, where you're the main actor and the main script writer, if _they_ are reluctant into placing a robot in that movie, right? :>

Comment: My guess is the studio would have passed on the script if they were, for some unknown reason, adamant about not having a robot in it.